# oracle php проблемы с соединением с БД

Tags: php, sql, oracle, регистрация

Добрый вечер, php-запрос не взаимодействует с БД.

вот мой код :

```
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
       $conn = oci_connect("hr", "qwerty", "127.0.0.1/XE");

       if(isset($_POST['submit']){
          $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
          $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
          $middlename = $_POST['middlename'];
          $login = $_POST['login'];
          $password = $_POST['password'];
          $r_password = $_POST['r_password'];
          if($password == $r_password){
             $password = md5($password);
             $q = oci_parse($conn, "INSERT INTO users (firstname,lastname,middlename,login,password) VALUE ($firstname,$lastname,$middlename,$login,$password)");
             oci_execute($q);
          }
          else die("Passwords must match!");
       }
    ?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
          <title>Кинофорум</title>
        </head>
       <body>
          <H1>Форма регистрации</H1>
           <form method="post" action="index.php">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="| Firstname" required /><br>
            <input type="text" name="laststname" placeholder="| Lastname" required /><br>
            <input type="text" name="middlename" placeholder="| Middlename" required /><br>
            <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="| Login" required /><br>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="| Password" required/><br>
            <input type="password" name="r_password" placeholder="| Repeat password" required /><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
          </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Страничка пустая и даже нет сообщений об ошибке.

скрин действующей таблицы users : https://pp.vk.me/c627227/v627227646/23b1/FjUx4RLuxuA.jpg

Подскажите где я ошибся, я новичок и годного материала на просторах очень, заранее благодарен.

Comment: Подземный стук мы тут не лечим. Приведите минимальный фрагмент кода, на котором воспроизводится ошибка.

Comment: Меня пугает наличие Oracle и Bobby Tables в одном параграфе. Ну и подлый обман про XHTML в довесок.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно после `oci_execute($q);` добавить `oci_commit($conn);` , так сказать подтвердить все.
Ну и закрыть соединение `oci_close($conn);`